# How to include null datetime in between clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to select data between devicetime='2017-04-06 10:06:57' and devicetime='2017-04-06 10:07:05' but the result doesn't include the devicetime with null value.

```
select * from positions where devicetime between '2017-04-06 10:06:57' and '2017-04-06 10:07:05' and deviceId=2
```

i tried this query above but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be careful about using `between` with `datetime` values.  Often, you want a strict less than on the upper value.

In any case, you are just looking for basic logic:

```
select p.*
from positions p
where (device time is null or
       devicetime between '2017-04-06 10:06:57' and '2017-04-06 10:07:05'
      ) and
      deviceId = 2;
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it gives me all the null value

Comment: Isn't that wat you wanted?Please be more specific.

Comment: i want data between '2017-04-06 10:06:57' and '2017-04-06 10:07:05' look at the image to see because you query gave more data

Comment: So your data is ordered by ascending id and devicetime, and you want all id's between the lowest devicetime and the highest in your range?

Then dnoeth seems to have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
select * from positions where (devicetime between '2017-04-06 10:06:57' and '2017-04-06 10:07:05' and deviceId=2) or devicetime is null
```

Answer (score 0):

So just add a null check as well.

```
select * 
from positions 
where (devicetime between '2017-04-06 10:06:57' and '2017-04-06 10:07:05' 
        or devicetime is null)  
    and deviceId=2
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you want something like this, should add back in the rows with null devicetime (but still deviceId = 2)

```
select * from positions 
where ((devicetime between '2017-04-06 10:06:57' and '2017-04-06 10:07:05') or  devicetime IS NULL)
and deviceId=2
```

Comment: thanks for you answer..but it gaves me all the null value..look at the image to see what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming there are additional rows with NULL outside of the shown data and `id` is sequential based on `devicetime`:

```
select * from positions 
where id between
  ( select MAX(id) from positions
    where devicetime <= '2017-04-06 10:06:57'
  )
and
  ( select MIN(id) from positions
    where devicetime >= '2017-04-06 10:07:05'
  )
and deviceId=2
```

If you know exact times you might also use

```
  ( select id from positions
    where devicetime = '2017-04-06 10:06:57'
  )
```

Or try to use `servertime` instead of `devicetime`, this seems to be NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **devicetime between '2017-04-06 10:06:57' and '2017-04-06 10:07:05' or devicetime = NULL and deviceId=2**

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like below

1.First way

```
SELECT * FROM positions WHERE (devicetime BETWEEN '2017-04-06 10:06:57' AND '2017-04-06 10:07:05' AND deviceId=2) OR (devicetime IS NULL AND deviceId=2)
```

---

2.second way

```
select * 
from positions 
where (devicetime between '2017-04-06 10:06:57' and '2017-04-06 10:07:05' 
        or devicetime is null)  
    and deviceId=2
```